# Open in browser not working for visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the open in browser extension (alt + b) for my visual studio code html, however it is not working even after attempting to uninstall and reinstall vsc again.
Extension id: techer.open-in-browser

```
Error code:
Open browser failed!! Please check if you have installed the browser chrome correctly!
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings --> Extensions --> Open in Browser and set a default browser.(Chrome, for example)

Comment: Tried this as well but doesnt seem to work.